# "usr/include/dbus-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation in maliit framework

Tags: c++, c, qt, cross-compiling

We are trying to compile `maliit` framework for `powerpc` from `Fedora` machine. Its giving the below warnings

> cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/dbus-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
>
> cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation

It seems that `maliit` is not getting fully cross compiled or it requires cross complied `dbus-1.0` and `glib-2.0 librar`.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply `dbus-1.0` and `glib-2.0` of the architecture you're cross-compiling for.

To do that, install those cross-compiled libaries in your system and use the option

`-L/path/to/your/ppc/libs/dir` and `-I/path/to/your/ppc/headers`.

And as pointed out by R in a comment below, Instead of using `#include <myheader.h>` for your dbus and glib specific headers you should use: `#include "myheader.h"`

Comment: I think the problem is that OP put absolute pathnames inside the `#include <>` directive.